# Error in the Nextjs' dashboard tutor project

Tags: next.js, documentation

I have been trying to learn Nextjs throught Nextjs tutor project. But in the Chapter 7 ( https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/fetching-data ) in " Fetching data for RevenueChart/ " I had a problem. [image: Error i got]

[image: fetchRevenue]

[image: This is how RevenueChart looks]

revenue-chart.tsx

```
import { generateYAxis } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { CalendarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import { lusitana } from '../font';
import { Revenue } from '@/app/lib/definitions';

// This component is representational only.
// For data visualization UI, check out:
// https://www.tremor.so/
// https://www.chartjs.org/
// https://airbnb.io/visx/

export default async function RevenueChart({
  revenue,
}: {
  revenue: Revenue[];
}) {
  const chartHeight = 350;
  // NOTE: comment in this code when you get to this point in the course

  const { yAxisLabels, topLabel } = generateYAxis(revenue);

  if (!revenue || revenue.length === 0) {
    return <p className="mt-4 text-gray-400">No data available.</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full md:col-span-4">
      <h2 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Recent Revenue
      </h2>
      {/* NOTE: comment in this code when you get to this point in the course */}

      <div className="rounded-xl bg-gray-50 p-4">
        <div className="mt-0 grid grid-cols-12 items-end gap-2 rounded-md bg-white p-4 sm:grid-cols-13 md:gap-4">
          <div
            className="mb-6 hidden flex-col justify-between text-sm text-gray-400 sm:flex"
            style={{ height: `${chartHeight}px` }}
          >
            {yAxisLabels.map((label) => (
              <p key={label}>{label}</p>
            ))}
          </div>

          {revenue.map((month) => (
            <div key={month.month} className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
              <div
                className="w-full rounded-md bg-blue-300"
                style={{
                  height: `${(chartHeight / topLabel) * month.revenue}px`,
                }}
              ></div>
              <p className="-rotate-90 text-sm text-gray-400 sm:rotate-0">
                {month.month}
              </p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center pb-2 pt-6">
          <CalendarIcon className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-500" />
          <h3 className="ml-2 text-sm text-gray-500 ">Last 12 months</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is the what i should to see in the localhost [image: What u should to see]

I tryed to fix the code in the revenue-chart.tsx

Comment: you need to share more details from your code e.g your `fetchRevenue` function. Your error seems to be related to the `revenue` variable not having a matching type to what you defined for it in `RevenueChart` - I can see that `revenue` variable is gotten from an async data fetch request. So assuming that the `fetchRevenue` function returns the right data type, isolate your data fetching into a `useEffect`, use a `useState` variable for `revenue` instead and assign the result to the state variable after it has been fetched.

Comment: @ZestMag77, Please don't upload images of code since this platform requires you to share the text of your code instead of images. Here's why. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors